# File transfer using FTP protocol in C#

Tags: c#, ftp, ftp-client

I have some Electronic devices, I have to copy files from my system to device and device to system using FTP protocol in C#. Currently I am doing with FileZilla. How I can transfer files(Folder/subfolders) using C# program.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`FtpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) and [`FtpWebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebresponse.aspx) classes.

`FtpWebRequest`:

> Implements a File Transfer Protocol (FTP) client.

`FtpWebResponse`:

> Encapsulates a File Transfer Protocol (FTP) server's response to a request.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to create an FTP client in VB.NET. You may also easily convert the code to C# as all .NET languages are CLI compliant:

http://dot-net-talk.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-create-ftp-client-in-vbnet.html